# List every record from Table A and check if the corresponding ID exists in Table B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables: Users, Groups, and Members.

```
Users
+---------+-----------+
| USER_ID | USER_NAME |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Bob       |
|       2 | John      |
+---------+-----------+

Groups
+----------+---------------+
| GROUP_ID |  GROUP_NAME   |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 | Administrator |
|        2 | Tester        |
|        3 | User          |
+----------+---------------+

Members
+---------+----------+
| USER_ID | GROUP_ID |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
|       1 |        3 |
|       2 |        2 |
|       2 |        3 |
+---------+----------+
```

I am trying to build a query to return a list of every GROUP_NAME and either TRUE or FALSE if a specified user is a part of the group or not.

The expected result for Bob would be:

```
+---------------+--------+
|  GROUP_NAME   | MEMBER |
+---------------+--------+
| Administrator | TRUE   |
| Tester        | TRUE   |
| User          | TRUE   |
+---------------+--------+
```

The expected result for John would be:

```
+---------------+--------+
|  GROUP_NAME   | MEMBER |
+---------------+--------+
| Administrator | FALSE  |
| Tester        | TRUE   |
| User          | TRUE   |
+---------------+--------+
```

This is my sudo code for the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_NAME, (TRUE or FALSE if USER_ID has a row with GROUP_ID) AS MEMBER
FROM Groups
JOIN Members
WHERE USER_ID = 1
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: How will you query this? Will you be passing/filtering by a single member at a time? Or can this be a view that returns all data for all user/group combinations (or lack thereof)? I would lean toward creating this as a view and then querying out which group you wanted to inspect. But the query for either case will be different. Can you share a bit more about how this will be used?

Comment: @jamie I am trying to get a list of a specific user's permissions to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a cross join to get all user/group combinations, then left join and use a conditional to determine presence or not:

```
declare @userId int = 2;

select      u.user_name,
            g.group_name,
            member = iif(m.user_id is null, 'false', 'true')
from        users u
cross join  groups g
left join   members m 
               on m.user_id = u.user_id
               and m.group_id = g.group_id
where       (u.user_id = @userId or @userId is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `exists` query:

```
select @specified_user_id as user_id, g.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from members m
                          where m.group_id = g.group_id and
                                m.user_id = @specified_user_id
                         )
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as user_in_group
from groups g;
```

If you want to specify the user by name, then you can do:

```
select u.user_name, g.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from members m
                          where m.group_id = g.group_id and
                                m.user_id = u.user_id
                         )
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as user_in_group
from groups g cross join
     (select u.*
      from users u
      where u.user_name = @specified_user_name
     ) u;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! The first query you posted works perfectly.

Comment: I am not sure who to give the credit for the answer to... both of you responded very quickly and both solutions work as expected!